# Install lxml on ubuntu 13.04 for python 3.3 Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, python-3.3

I have tried all of the following:

```
apt-get install python-lxml
apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev
pip install lxml (gives me a compile error, no pyconfig.h)
easy_install lxml
```

Eclipse still does not recognize it when I try to import:

```
from lxml import etree
```

Please help.

Comment: Does it work when you execute any script from terminal?

Comment: yes it does. I created a test scrip and it imports just fine

Answer (score 0):

Update your `PYTHONPATH` in Eclipse, go to `Preferences > PyDev > Interpreters - Python` Then update your paths to `lxml` package. I suggest you to reload your interpreter (first delete it, and next add it again) it will load all packages and PyDev will recognized `lxml`

Comment: Removed interpreter, added it again, still no luck. /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (where lxml is) is listed in the libraries when configuring the interpreter. Getting an auto complete option for lxml but no etree.

Comment: Try adding lxml.etree there too

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your script when you tried importing and were successful is running with the Python 2.x interpreter or whether it's using the Python 3.x interpreter? I suspect that `python-lxml` is only installing a Python 2.x version of `lxml`. Try `python3-lxml`.

Alternatively, if you wish to install using `pip`, your `pip` install of `lxml`'s error points to the lack of a `pyconfig.h` file which can be solved by `sudo apt-get install python3-dev` in your case (note that it's the `python3-dev` *not* `python-dev`, which only installs the required dev files for Python 2.x).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding **lxml** to the Forced Builtins found within Preferences:  PyDev -> Interpreters -> Python Interpreter, then select the *Forced Builtin* tab.  It fixed it for me.

http://pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html#PyDevInterpreterConfiguration-ForcedBuiltins